# Surprised that v1 of this program compiles but not v2. Is this by design? If so, why?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, covariance

**First version:**

```
public interface DeepCopyable<T>
{
  T deepCopy();
}

public interface Statement extends DeepCopyable<Statement>
{
}

public interface Expression
{
  Expression deepCopy(); // forgot I have an interface for this
}

public class Invocation implements Expression, Statement
{
  public final String Field;

  public Invocation(String field)
  {
    Field = field;
  }

  public Invocation deepCopy()
  {
    return new Invocation(Field);
  }
}
```

**Second Version, Update Expression Interface:**

```
public interface Expression extends DeepCopyable<Expression>
{
}
```

But now I get the compilation error

```
Error: C:\temp\Invocation.java:1: DeepCopyable cannot be inherited with different arguments: <Expression> and <Statement>
```

I can understand this error message in the general case where the return types are invariant; however, if I inherit the same interface twice with return types A and B and, further, the implementing method returns C where C is covariant wrt A and B, shouldn't this be safe?

Comment: Can you please post the full code for the second version because I don't get any compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

In Invocation class, you are extending two Interfaces Expression and Statement, in second version of your code what happens is your Expression interface is extending the DeepcCopyable interface as shown below.

```
class Invocation implements Expression, Statement {...}




interface Statement extends DeepCopyable<Statement> {
}

interface Expression extends DeepCopyable<Expression> {
}
```

In your code what happens is when you implements two interfaces  Expression and Statement which is extending to different Generics, here what happens is compiler gets confused that what to consider, hence it will not allow you to implement both the interfaces  Expression, Statement for  the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement an interface twice with different parameters. That's the problem with the second version.

The problem with the first version is that both its interfaces specify `deepCopy` with slightly different signature. However, the signature that it implements is compatible with both of them, so there is no problem.